# NodeJS Request Pipe buffer size

Tags: node.js, request, aws-lambda

How can I set up the maximum buffer size on a NodeJS [Request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) Pipe? I'm trying to use [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) to download from a `source` and pipe upload to a `destination` like in the code below:

```
request(source).pipe(request(destination))
```

This code works fine, but if the file size is bigger than the AWS Lambda Memory Size (image below), **it crashes**. If I increase the memory, it works, so I know is not the timeout or link, but only the memory allocation. Initially I don't to increase the number, but even if I use the maximum, still 1.5GB, and I'm expecting to transfer files bigger than that.

[image]

Is there a global variable for NodeJS on AWS Lambda for this? Or any other suggestion?

Comment: Read this: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_buffering Pipes automatically manage the data flow to _prevent_ the memory-usage getting out of control, so I'm not sure if the code you're showing is the actual cause of your problems.

Comment: It fails if the AWS Lambda memory is smaller than the file, so I know is the memory. NodeJS may allocate up to 2GB, right? But I would like something smaller, maybe 128MB just like AWS Lambda settings. Here is the full source, but it's basically the one at the question: https://github.com/augustogoncalves/bim360appstore-data.management-nodejs-transfer.storage/blob/master/server/lambda/transfer.js#L42

Comment: And you're not uploading to Box.com in your test case? That part of the code reads the entire source file into memory.

Comment: yes, the BOX piece is an exception, still need to fix it. But the second piece uses PIPE and it's the one that is failing due memory...

Comment: Try adding error handlers, perhaps there's an underlying error that's causing the problem. But I don't see why that code would read the entire source file into memory; like I said, `.pipe()` should prevent that from happening (although _perhaps_ `request` itself is causing it).

Comment: about Box, added that exception as I could not pipe with multipart upload, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45037394/request-get-pipe-to-reqest-post-on-box

Answer (score 2):

Two things to consider:

1. Do not use request(source).pipe(request(destination)) with or within a promise (async/await). For some reason it memory leaks when done with promises.

"However, STREAMING THE RESPONSE (e.g. .pipe(...)) is DISCOURAGED because Request-Promise would grow the memory footprint for large requests unnecessarily high. Use the original Request library for that. You can use both libraries in the same project." Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise

2. To control how much memory the pipe uses: Set the highWaterMark for BOTH ends of the pipe. I REPEAT: BOTH ENDS OF THE PIPE. This will force the pipe to let only so much data into the pipe and out of the pipe, and thus limits its occupation in memory. (But does not limit how fast data moves through the pipe...see Bonus)

request.get(sourceUrl,{highWaterMark: 1024000, encoding:null}).pipe(request(destinationUrl,{highWaterMark: 1024000));

1025000 is in bytes and is approximately 10MB.

Source for highWaterMark background: 
"Because Duplex and Transform streams are both Readable and Writable, each maintains two separate internal buffers used for reading and writing, allowing each side to operate independently of the other while maintaining an appropriate and efficient flow of data. For example, net.Socket instances are Duplex streams whose Readable side allows consumption of data received from the socket and whose Writable side allows writing data to the socket. Because data may be written to the socket at a faster or slower rate than data is received, it is important for each side to operate (and buffer) independently of the other." <- last sentence here is the important part.

https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options

3. Bonus: If you want to throttle how fast data passes through the pipe, check something like this out: https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-throttle

const throttle  = require('stream-throttle');

let th = new throttle.Throttle({rate: 10240000}); //if you dont want to transfer data faster than 10mb/sec

request.get(sourceUrl,{highWaterMark: 1024000, encoding:null}).pipe(th).pipe(request(destinationUrl,{highWaterMark: 1024000));